# NodeJS and Socket.io creating room with two users

Tags: node.js, mongoose, socket.io

I'm doing chat app and I want to do it real time. Chat will be for now between two users. When user access to chat it finds all messages between them and displays messages. I think I need to create room with two users and then store room id in database. But I'm new to socket.io and I need advice how to do it.

Comment: write a server that just responds to some route call ... later this server will also handle mongo but ignore that now ... then write a client who sends a string to the server using websockets ... beauty of websockets is once such a connection is made that connection stays open for two way comms ... later add ability for server to recognize each new client connection ... then add ability for client A to send a string to the server with annotation to have server forward this string over to client B ... each additional functionality is simple

Answer (score 1):

Try to take some already pretty wide used chat, like Slack, as example. Usually you need pretty same set of things, workplaces, channels, private messages (like room but for two users only), and have users sending text messages with some formatting or images or just any files. Just take it easy, plan and make it step by step.

Also take note, that for both parties have their chat view updated with new messages you need not only save message one user send to db, but also broadcast that message to everyone, involved in conversation.

Comment: It's too hard for me now, I need take time to learn it and I don't have so much time now so I decided for now if user not writing it refreshes chat page every 10 seconds